# Apache Redirects - .htaccess - ReWriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to manipulate the .htaccess file on my blogs server to allow certain content to be redirected while allowing others to be accessed.

What I would like to do, is allow any file with the extension of `(gif|jpg|css|js|ico|png)` to be accessed along with a directory `/includes/` and a file `sitemap.html` while all other traffic I would like to send to the sitemap.html file.

Is this possible?

Here's the code that I'm trying to use but it doesn't appear to be working as ecpected.  The redirect matched the file extensions and allows the `sitemap.html` file to be accessed but the `/includes/` directory that I want to be allowed access to froma user perspective regardless of what files are in the actual directory still appears to be redirecting to the sitemap.html file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.(gif|jpg|css|js|ico|png)$|^/includes$|^/sitemap\.html$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sitemap.html [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `$` from `^/includes$`, as it prevents matching anything but the bare `/includes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|css|js|ico|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(sitemap\.html|includes(/.*|))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /sitemap.html [R=301,L]
```

Sure both RewriteCond lines can be combined into 1 but I would suggest keeping it 2 separate as this is easier to read and easy to maintain in case you want to add new extensions or new directories for exclusion in future.

Comment: What does `RewriteRule ^ /sitemap.html [R=301,L]` do?

Comment: That forwards current URL to `/sitemap.html` if above 2 conditions are successful.